# Wicket RadioChoice returns null all the time

Tags: wicket

how is said in the title I can not to resolve this problem for several hours. I hope I will get some useful replies, thank you.

wicket version: 1.5.7

```
public class EvalSearcherPage extends MenuPage {
   ...
   private Code selectedEvalChoice;
   ... 

   ...
   RadioChoice<Code> evalRadioChoice = new RadioChoice<Code>("evalRadioChoice", new PropertyModel<Code>(this, "selectedEvalChoice"), EVAL_CHOICES, new ChoiceRenderer<Code>(getLocaleColumn()));
    evalRadioChoice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                ...
            target.add(...);
        }
    });
    evalChoiceForm.add(evalRadioChoice);
            ...
```

in constructor: 
EVAL_CHOICES is filled by choices, 
selectedEvalChoice is filled by default choice

Everything works good till the moment when I want to select another choice. After that RadioChoice saves null to selectedEvalChoice.

So where is the problem, could anybody help, please?

Btw getter and setter are implemented for selectedEvalChoice but I learned that is not necessary.

Comment: Try `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` instead: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/OnChangeAjaxBehavior.html

Answer (score 2):

For RadioChoice you have to use AjaxForm*Choice*ComponentUpdatingBehavior.

Check your log output, you should find a warning there.